# Can adverb be used after "so" instead of adjective?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Compare these sentences:

> The driver in front shouldn't have stopped **so sudden**.
>
> The driver in front shouldn't have stopped **so suddenly**.

The second sentence was taken from my book, but that was the first time I've ever seen. I'm more familiar with "**so** + **adjective**" form, such as "you are so beautiful, he's so handsome, etc."

So, both sentences above are correct?

Comment: The opinion essay was **so well** **written**, and **so convincingly**  argued it got an A.

Comment: There are irregular adverbs e.g good--well, and flat adverbs, where the adjective and its adverb remain unchanged e.g fast-- fast (not *fastly*) and slow --slow ( but also *slowly*). The adjective *sudden* follows the normal pattern ), i.e the suffix "ly" is added.

Comment: "So" can modify an adjective used as a predicative complement ("He was so nice"), but not an adverb. In your example "sudden(ly)" modifies the verb "stopped", and thus must be an _ly_ adverb modified by the optional modifier "so".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**so**" can indeed be used with either an adjective or an adverb to make it stronger. Your second sentence is grammatically correct. Your first sentence is wrong because you are using an adjective to describe the verb "stop". We stop **suddenly** (adverb), not sudden (adjective). You sing **well** (adverb), not good (adjective).

[This page](https://learnenglishkids.britishcouncil.org/grammar-practice/adverbs) has games and examples to help you with adverbs, and there's a useful page on the use of "so" and "such" [here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/so-and-such).

Answer (score 1):

Only the second sentence is correct. You can use an adverb after "so", and you must if the phrase is modifying the verb. The word "so" will have the same sense, indicating, more or less, *to a previously indicated or implied degree*.